# How to rescan/rebuild /dev/sdx after "raw" dd restoration

Tags: dd, synchronization, sfdisk

I'd like to know how to request Linux to update /dev/sdx after doing a "raw" dd restoration of a whole hard disk partitions ?

I have to use dd instead of sfdisk to restore the partition tables of an old Windows 98 PC (because of my old BIOS). It works fine except that the /dev/sda1 /dev/sda2 etc... block devices do not appear immediately after that. If I launch "gparted", they then appear, but I'd like to do this in a CLI way.

There must be some command that gparted launches at start that does this sync or update, but I've not been able to pinpoint it (I tried the Linux "sync" command, with no success).

Thanks for any help or hint on that.